# How to loop through a directory and skip folders containing a specific string?

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, command-line

I am currently scanning an entire directory, copying an exe over and running it in each folder.  This exe converts certain log files within each folder.  However, half the directories don't contain any log files and it seems like a waste to move into each of those folders and run an exe that does nothing.  An example of some folder names:

- 0075D-S10
- 0075D-S10-EVT
- 0132C-S10
- 0132C-S10-EVT
- and so on...

I basically only need to copy the executable into the folders that **don't** contain EVT in the name.  These just contain evtx files that aren't important to me at the moment.

Here is a snippet of my batch file and what it is doing:

```
set back=%cd%
set current_dir=%cd%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%i in ("%current_dir%\*") do (
   copy LogCsv.exe "%%i" >NULL
   cd "%%i"
   LogCsv.exe
   )
cd %back%
```

Really my first time just using Batch files and I've been exploring answers on here, but couldn't find a solution to this particular problem.  How can I loop this directory, excluding any folders containing the "EVT" string in their name?

Thanks for taking time to assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use `findstr /v` to exclude certain values from search results.

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
set current_dir=%cd%
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad %current_dir%\* ^| findstr /v EVT') do (
     copy LogCsv.exe "%%i" >NUL
     cd "%%i"
     LogCsv.exe
     cd %back%
)
```

Also note, you need to pipe to `nul` not `null`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  This seems to only copy the exe to the first folder before looping and saying "This directory is invalid".  Meaning the exe only executes within one folder.  Also null has been working for me, isn't the difference that null can be used with cmd and Powershell?

Comment: edited answer, I only focused on the actual question, not your code.. try it now please.. also,  `null` will create a file called `null` where `nul` means pipe to nothing.. so it will not display the output.

Comment: Question... I do not know logCsv. Does it have to be copied into each dir? Can you not run it with a path switch? I.e `LogCsv.exe %%i`

Comment: @StevenGibb why do you need the `CD` commands? Couldn't you just execute the program with the folder name you found? `"%%i\logcsv.exe"`

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't working as expected.  Just getting a "File not found" error now.  I'll have to spend some more time on it!  The logCsv is an in house exe and it runs from same directory as a specific log file that is created from a different application.  Other users were manually moving it into sub directories to use it.  I tried some variation of running it from one directory and it would never work, so this was a workaround where it would be copied and removed once the csv was generated.

Comment: @Squashman - Yes, that would make a lot more sense actually.  Let me give that a try too.  Thanks.

Comment: Would this single line batch file command do what you're wanting? `@For /D %%A In (*) Do @PushD "%%A" 2>Nul && (Copy /Y "%~dp0LogCsv.exe">Nul&PopD)`?

Comment: @Compo - Unfortunately not.   I've just went with the original implementation, even if it copies a file to folders it doesn't need to.  Other ideas here are not working as intended.  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Steven, my comment was to simplify the methodology, not to answer the entire question, _I would have reserved that for the answer area!_. Anyhow, to check the directory, just before the `Copy` instruction, you could check the last five characters of `%__CD__%` doesn't equal `-EVT\ `.

Comment: @Steven. Let me take this a step back. Use your original code. Simply replace your for loop up to the do function. `for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad %current_dir% ^| findstr /v EVT') do `

Comment: @Compo - I understand that.  I'm saying your suggestion didn't work for simplifying the methodology.  The entire behavior of the batch file changed.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - I have tried replacing that as you suggested.  The command window just immediately closes now when trying to run it.  Just going back to original implementation for now.  Thank you.